# startswith TypeError in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
    def readFasta(filename):
        """ Reads a sequence in Fasta format """
        fp = open(filename, 'rb')
        header = ""
        seq = ""
        while True:
            line = fp.readline()
            if (line == ""):
                break
            if (line.startswith('>')):
                header = line[1:].strip()
            else:
                seq = fp.read().replace('\n','')
                seq = seq.replace('\r','')          # for windows
                break
        fp.close()
        return (header, seq)

    FASTAsequence = readFasta("MusChr01.fa")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

But the first argument to `startswith` is supposed to be a string according to the docs... so what is going on?

I'm assuming I'm using at least Python 3 since I'm using the latest version of LiClipse.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's because you're opening the file in bytes mode, and so you're calling `bytes.startswith()` and not `str.startswith()`.

You need to do `line.startswith(b'>')`, which will make `'>'` a [bytes literal](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: Ah I added b before all the strings and now it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm on a sidenote, seq = fp.read().replace(b'\n',b'') seems to be messing up the stuff that's read.  Not sure what's going on but it only seems to be iterating twice (in a 190mb file) and outputting b' each time.

Comment: This is not backwards compatible.

Comment: The problem is on first argument, not the second, so `line.startswith(b'>')` cannot possibly solve it. `bytes(line).startswith('>')`, on the other hand, could.

Comment: @mpiskore I used (based on this answer) `line.endswith(b'\n')` and I think it works well.

Answer (score 2):

If remaining to open a file in binary, replacing 'STR' to bytes('STR'.encode('utf-8')) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your file to test on try encoding to utf-8 on the 'open'

```
fp = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```