# why adding b, before string solves TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, startswith

Following the first answer given to question: [startswith TypeError in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827615/startswith-typeerror-in-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Why adding the b before the string works, what does it mean?