# Upgrade Django project to Python3 - migrations fail

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a Django project which has been developed with Python2.7, it is currently using Django version 1.10. I am now in the process of upgrading - first to Python3, and then afterwards I will do the Django upgrade.

When I make Python3 virtual environment and run the tests:

```
venv bash% ./manage.py tests
```

I get a massive traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line( sys.argv )
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 29, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 72, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 549, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 499, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 743, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 70, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 130, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 202, in handle
    targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 132, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 237, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 271, in create_model
    self.quote_name(field.column),
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 115, in quote_name
    return self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "/home/hove/sleipner/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 153, in quote_name
    if name.startswith('"') and name.endswith('"'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

As I understand it the problem is unicode/string issues in the migrations? I have tried to follow the advice: "Add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top every module". The resulting code still works nicely in Python2.7, but `manage.py test` fails in the same way for Python3.

For all it is worth the project seems to "basically" work in Python3 when I do:

```
bash% manage.py runserver
```

**Update:**

These are my database settings - might very well be something wrong with this, but observe that it has worked in Python2.7 for many years - and still does:

```
if "test" in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = { 'default' : {
        "ENGINE" : "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME" : "friskby.sqlite",
        "TEST" : {
            "NAME" : "friskby-test.sqlite"}}}
else:
    DATABASE_URL = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
    if DATABASE_URL:
        config = dj_database_url.config(default = DATABASE_URL)
        DATABASES = { 'default': config }
    else:
        raise Exception("The DATABASE_URL environment variable has not bee set")
```

Comment: Can you show your DATABASES settings? It looks like something might be wrong there.

Comment: I have updated with DATABASE settings.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19827633/8601393

Comment: @user422005 do any of your models' fields specify a `db_column` attribute?

Comment: Yes - I have (for historical reasons) quite a lot of `db_column` attributes; is that a smoking gun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from @Will Keeling set me on the right track. My migrations (originally created with Python2.7) had many:

```
... db_column = b"NAME_OF_COLUMN", ...
```

statements. I just removed all the leading `b` - and lo and behold all tests pass in both Python2.7 and Python3.